# .Net Core 5 -A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Tags: c#, httpclient, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm getting this error:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

In the program (.NET Core 5), I call an external service that works over 80% correctly, but 20% of the time I encounter the error I mentioned above.

What should I do?

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40);

    var authenticationString = $"authenticationString";
    var base64EncodedAuthenticationString = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authenticationString));

    string baseUrl = @"https://service.sdpms.ir/api/internalTrade/checkCustomer";
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64EncodedAuthenticationString);

    SdpmsCheckCustomer data = new SdpmsCheckCustomer();
    data.AuthenticationCode = "AuthenticationCode";
    data.Data.CustomerId = melliCode;

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await client.PostAsync(baseUrl, content);

    var res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<sdpmsOutput<SdpmsCustomer>>(res);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: is it possible that external service is available 80% of the time and *not* available 20% of the time, making the error explaining what is happening?

Comment: I raised this issue with that service owner, they do not confirm such an assumption

Comment: oh well! then you need to troubleshoot the assumption with that service owner - I don't thing there is anything in the code itself that would cause this issue

Comment: Maybe put a retry logic to call the API again when a failure is encountered and keep trying until a success response comes back.

Comment: is it possible it occurs because of too many requests?
near 1000 per min

Comment: Yea, they could have a limit on the number of requests a single user can send. Or the server is just generally overloaded by this large number of requests.